# Display unique characters in dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a data frame of unique object names. I need to create a list of all unique characters used in the column. Is there a way to display a list of all unique characters used in a column?

Example data:

```
Performance PM
Truck Tips - B - 2001
ASE Parts Specialist (P1)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
-
(
1
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
data <- "Example data:
Performance PM
Truck Tips - B - 2001
ASE Parts Specialist (P1)"


sort(unique(strsplit(data,"")[[1]]))
```

```r
 [1] "-"  " "  "\n" "("  ")"  ":"  "0"  "1"  "2"  "a"  "A"  "B"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "E"  "f"  "i"  "k"  "l"  "m"  "M"  "n"  "o"  "p"  "P" 
[27] "r"  "s"  "S"  "t"  "T"  "u"  "x"
```